# React Component: Need to Click + or - Button Twice to Update Count - What's Causing This Behavior?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

In my React component, I have implemented functionality to increment and decrement the count of products in a shopping cart by clicking the "+" and "-" buttons. However, I'm encountering an issue where I need to click these buttons twice to see the count change. This behavior is unexpected, and I'm seeking help to identify and resolve the problem.

I have a React component named `Cart` that retrieves the cart data from an API and displays it. It uses the `updatecartcount` function from Redux-Toolkit to update the product count in the cart.

```
import { Box, Button, Grid, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import axios from 'axios'
import { ErrorMessage } from 'formik'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { updatecartcount } from './updatecount'

export default function Cart() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [cart, setcart] = useState([])
  const [error, seterror] = useState('')
        
  async function getcart() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://ecommerce.routemisr.com/api/v1/cart', {
        headers: { token: localStorage.getItem('acesstoken') }
      });
      console.log(response.data.data.products);
      setcart(response.data.data);
    } catch (err) {
      seterror(err);
    }
  }         
            
  useEffect(() => {
    getcart()
  },[])

  return
    <>
      <Typography variant='h6'>your cart</Typography>
        <Typography variant='h6'>total cart price : {cart.totalCartPrice} EGP</Typography>
        {cart.products? cart.products.map((product) => 
          <Grid
            container sx={{
              width: 3/4,
              margin: 'auto',
              display: 'flex',
              alignItems: 'center'
            }}
          >
            <Grid md={1}> 
              <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: 'red', width: '100%' }}>
                <img
                  src={product.product.imageCover}
                  width={'100%'}
                />
              </Box>
            </Grid>
            <Grid md={9}> 
              <Box
                sx={{
                  width: '100%',
                  display: 'flex',
                  justifyContent: 'space-between',
                  alignItems: 'center'
                }}
              > 
              <Box>
                <Typography
                  sx={{
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    marginRight: '1rem'
                  }}
                >
                  product: {product.product.title}
                </Typography>
                <Typography sx={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                  price={product.price}
                </Typography>
              </Box>
              <Box
                sx={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center'
                }}
              >
                <Button
                  onClick={() => {
                    dispatch(updatecartcount({
                      id: product.product._id,
                      count: product.count - 1
                    }))
                    getcart()
                  }}
                >
                  -
                </Button>
                <Typography>{product.count}</Typography>
                <Button
                  onClick={() => {
                    dispatch(updatecartcount({
                      id: product.product._id, 
                      count: product.count + 1
                    }))
                      .then(getcart())
                  }}
                >
                  +
                </Button>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      ) : ''}
    </>
}
```

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const updatecartcount = createAsyncThunk(
  'cartcount/updatecartcount',
  async function ({ id, count }) {
    let { data }= axios.put(
      `https://ecommerce.routemisr.com/api/v1/cart/${id}`,
      {
        count: count
      },
      {
        headers: {
          token: localStorage.getItem('acesstoken')
        }
      }
    )
    return data
  }
)

export const updatecartslice = createSlice({
  name: 'cartCount',
  initialState: {
    cartcount: []
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(updatecartcount.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.cartcount = action.payload
    })
  }
})

export const updateCountSlice=updatecartslice.reducer
```

How can I ensure that the count updates immediately after clicking the buttons just once?
Are there any potential issues in my React component or Redux implementation that could be causing this problem?

Comment: Why are you storing the cart data in local component state instead of in the Redux store? What is the purpose of the `cartCount` state? What is returned from the PUT request? What "counts" aren't updating as expected when dispatching the action, where in the code/UI? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: get cart is only to fetch cart data in cart component. 
update count only to modify count

Answer (score -1):

To run code after `fulfilled` or `error` on `dispatch`, try to unwrap it first to get a Promise-like behaviour.

```
dispatch(
    updatecartcount({
    id: product.product._id,
    count: product.count + 1,
    })
)
.unwrap()
.then(getcart());
```

From [Redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#checking-thunk-results-in-components)

> However, it's common to want to write logic that looks at the success
> or failure of the actual request that was made. Redux Toolkit adds a
> `.unwrap()` function to the returned Promise, which will return a new
> Promise that either has the actual `action.payload` value from a
> `fulfilled` action, or `throws an error` if it's the rejected action. This
> lets us handle success and failure in the component using normal
> try/catch logic. So, we'll clear out the input fields to reset the
> form if the post was successfully created, and log the error to the
> console if it failed.

Comment: still not working

Comment: it works by adding dependencies
 useEffect(()=>{
    getcart()
},[updatecartcount])

Comment: Does it work without the unwrap()?

Comment: yes but by clicking twice on the button